# Did Pharaoh attempt to kill Moses during the plagues

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, capital-punishment, egypt, plagues-makkos, parashas-shemos

Given that Moses was a wanted fugitive ([Ex.2:15](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9863#v=15)) and that he was destroying the land of egypt with the plagues, and a general nuisance to Pharaoh were there attempts to kill him by Pharaoh. (by for example, asking his army to shoot arrows at him)

Comment: according to Rashi 2:23, and perhaps the simple meaning of the pasuk in Shemos 4:19, Moshe was no longer a wanted fugitive

Comment: @Matt ok but he was certainly a threat to national security, dont you think?

Comment: Very true. I wouldn't be surprised if midrashim fill in that part of the story

Comment: As Moshe was needed to stop each plague, Pharaoh couldn't kill him whilst any plague was in progress. And then at each stage Pharaoh naively believed there wouldn't be another one.

Comment: @CashCow could also have asked before the plagues began

Comment: Well, how much do you trust Yul Brynner's intentions? :-)

Comment: "ויצליני מחרב פרעה" (Shemos 18:4): He saved me from the sword of Pharaoh. There were attempt to kill him, but they couldn't manage it.